# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, ssh-tunnel

I'm working with Python, Flask, and SQLAlchemy.
I've been using a local database while building my application, and it has been working fine with the following code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config[
    'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = \
    'mysql+pymysql://<username>:<password>@localhost/<DBName>'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Now, I'm trying to get this code to connect to a remote database using the Python package sshtunnel.  Here is what this code looks like:

```
from flask import Flask
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

forwarding_server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    '1.2.3.4', #my host IP address
    ssh_username="user",
    ssh_password="password",
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 8080)
)

forwarding_server.start()
local_port = str(forwarding_server.local_bind_port)
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config[
    'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = \
    'mysql+pymysql://<username>:<password>@127.0.0.1:' + local_port + '/<DBName>'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

It SEEMS like this is connecting, but immediately after launching my flask application, I'm receiving the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
```

Any insight into this issue would be helpful.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You can set `SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE` to a value less than `SQLALCHEMY_POOL_TIMEOUT` in configuration of `Flask-SQLAlchemy`. Check the [timeouts](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/config/#timeouts) part of the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I'm not sure if this is related to my issue or not.  I am working with MariaDB, and the notes in the docs specify that MariaDB does like to throw this issue.  I attempted to add the following lines of code to no avail:  app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_TIMEOUT'] = 600
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE'] = 100
I'm not sure, using the app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'], how to properly set this.  I ended up just opening up the MySQL database to allow external connections, and that's working.  Not sure if I should be using SSH tunnel instead?

Comment: I have also tried variants of this advice, and it does not work. Other threads also report that it doesn't always work.

Answer (score 1):

I tried pool_recycle value less than wait_timeout (used 50 for mariadb database), but I do not know why it didn't work for me! Using an explicit pre_ping and session rollback / close within a try / except block work for me. I used this decorator below to wrap all my functions and that solved my problem:

```
def manage_session(f):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):

        # MANUAL PRE PING
        try:
            db.session.execute("SELECT 1;")
            db.session.commit()
        except:
            db.session.rollback()
        finally:
            db.session.close()

        # SESSION COMMIT, ROLLBACK, CLOSE
        try:
            res = f(*args, **kwargs)
            db.session.commit()
            return res
        except Exception as e:
            db.session.rollback()
            raise e
            # OR return traceback.format_exc()
        finally:
            db.session.close()
    return inner
```

and then decorated my functions like below:

```
@manage_session
def my_function(*args, **kwargs):
    return "result"
```

Answer (score 1):

When you specify SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI you tell flask_sqlalchemy this is an open session which is being asserted on app_context.

When exiting app_context [flask_sqlalchemy is closing active sessions](https://github.com/pallets-eco/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/2.5.1/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L886), including your DB session

I don't know your application's flow, but do your best to close DB session before exiting app_context, and be sure you know exactly where a new DB session is being created and used in app_context.